# Forward Lookup Zones in DNS Manager should I use domain name or server name

Tags: web-hosting, dns-zone, dns-hosting

The server that I use for hosting web apps has been moved to a new location. I have a remote connection to it and have been trying to update the forward lookup zones to the reflect the new ip address. My question is, under Type Name Server (NS) should my FQDN be the name of the server, or the domainname.com?

I have been searching around and have had no luck getting my sites back up. I am wondering if I have my FQDN wrong because at this point anything could be wrong.

I am also wondering if I have my zone files configured wrong, but they get updated everything time I apply changes to my forward lookup zones.

I have gone to the godaddy account and under DNS changed the A record to point to the new public ip address of the server, but under nameservers in godaddy it says that it is using the default name servers, which I have never changed, they are the same as they were before the server was moved to a location.

I am wondering if I should use my mydomainname.com as the FQDN under Name Servers on DNS Manager? Or use the name of the server? Or the default name servers specified in the godaddy account.

Answer (score 0):

Your NS records must point to your domain's nameservers. This has nothing to do with your web site.

It sounds like GoDaddy is hosting your nameservers. In this case you make changes to your own DNS records in their control panel that they provide to you. But you do not change the NS records, because those must point to the nameservers.

Comment: Okay so in the control panel I will edit the a record to point to my new ip address but leave the nameserver records alone. But then in my DNS Manager, do I change the name server records to display my own domain namerservers or godaddy nameservers?

Comment: @stupidQuestions You don't change the NS records.